# How to remove TFS bindings from a Codeplex project

Tags: svn, tfs, codeplex, source-control-bindings

I have a couple of projects hosted on Codeplex. Since I didn't really have a clue about anything but TFS when I created them, I used that. But, now I have gotten more comfortable with TortoiseSVN and VisualSVN so I would like to use that instead.

Of course, to get my project using subversion is no problem. The thing is that the projects have TFS bindings in them. How can I remove these? Would be nice with a step by step guide.

*And so you don't have to wonder what tools I have: I can connect to the projects with both the TFS Explorer thing in Visual Studio and with TortoiseSVN. I also have TFS power tools installed, so I can use those too if needed.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. File -> Source Control -> Change Source Control.
2. Highlight all rows, click Unbind, OK.
3. Save.
4. Tools -> Options -> Source Control.
5. Pick desired VS plugin, OK.
6. Solution Explorer -> rightclick -> Add To Source Control.
7. Follow the instructions in the new provider's wizard.

There are some binding commands in tfpt but they're all about adding TFS bindings, not removing them.